# How can I get JSLint to stop complaining about Ember.js ".property()"s?

Tags: javascript, properties, ember.js, jslint

How can I get JSLint to stop complaining about Ember.js ".property()"s in my model definitions?

E.g., when given:

```
isBlah: function() {
    "use strict";
    ...
}.property("foo", "bar").cacheable()
```

JSLint complains about:

```
Unexpected '.'.
```

on the line with the .property() call. This happens for every occurrence of ".property()" which makes JSLint output full of "noise" and less than fully helpful...

Comment: Have you looked on the jslint Yahoo group page?

Comment: Maybe switch to [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/about/) :)

Comment: Tomasz... JSHint was certainly less noisy! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Ember [documents](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/) the following method to avoid the function prototype extensions.

Instead of **.property()**, use **Ember.computed()**:

```
fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
  return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
})
```

Instead of **.observes()**, use **Ember.observer()**:

```
fullNameDidChange: Ember.observer('fullName', function() {
  console.log("Full name changed");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to convert it to:

```
isBlah: Em.property(function() {
    "use strict";
    ...
}, "foo", "bar").cacheable()
```

Where I first add the 'property' method to Ember (before starting my app):

```
Em.property = function (func) {
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return Function.prototype.property.apply(func, params);
};
```

Comment: This way you have similar syntax, and can still use jslint (which enforces more validations than jshint).

Comment: Note that it only runs once (when creating the class), hence no performance overhead.

Comment: Was there a reason to do that rather than Em.computed(fn).property(...)?

Comment: I later found a similar implementation now exists in Ember :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to configure this at the moment. You can manually alter jslint though.

In `jslint.js` around line 3397 (version 2013-11-23) you will find these lines

```
    case '.':
        if (peek().string !== 'bind' || peek(1).id !== '(') {
            next_token.warn('unexpected_a');
        }
        break;
```

Comment out that if statement and the warnings will go away!

```
    case '.':
        // if (peek().string !== 'bind' || peek(1).id !== '(') {
        //     next_token.warn('unexpected_a');
        // }
        break;
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Though while you're at it, instead of just commenting out everything you could add `property`, `on` and `observes` to the list of accepted methods. That way you keep the warnings for anything unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Arne's solution is along the right track. BUT JSlint won't warn you about some stuff. Instead of commenting out the relevant lines change around line 3387 of `jslint.js`

```
case '.':
    if (peek().string !== 'bind' || peek(1).id !== '(') {
        next_token.warn('unexpected_a');
    }
    break;
```

To this (line 2)

```
    case '.':
        if (peek().string !== 'bind' && peek().string !== 'property' || peek(1).id !== '(') {
            next_token.warn('unexpected_a');
        }
        break;
```